# Fatal Error: Allowed Memory Size Exhausted In XAMPP

Tags: memory, xampp, out-of-memory, size, fpdf

Right now I was printing all of my data into a PDF using FPDF and those data contains pictures with a large image sizes. Then my the XAMPP promt like following text below. What is the following solution in order for me to proceed printing? Is their a solution without changing the images size?

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 50933016 bytes) in C:\xampp\htdocs\techgirl\reports\fpdf.php on line 1449
```

Even I tried to change the memory limit in my `php.ini` into 900M nothing happen.

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Change the memory_limit option in your php.ini to your needs.

Comment: Updated the question sir!!

Comment: Have you restarted apache after the change? If it still doesn't work use phpinfo(); in your php file to get all php infos, the memory limit should be listened in the Core section.

Comment: Not yet! Is that required??

Comment: If you Change something in the php.ini or appache.conf it will always require a restart or reload.

Comment: Thanks works fine. Just need to restart. Now I know. Thanks!

Comment: @user7843796 How much is your final memory limit?

Answer (score 3):

Change the memory_limit option in your php.ini to your needs.

Then Restart the Apache server from XAMPP

Answer (score 2):

Change memory_limit to -1 in php.ini. i.e memory_limit=-1 
You can find php.ini file in bin/php/

Comment: While this might be a valuable hint to solve the problem, a good answer also demonstrates the solution. Please [EDIT](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59640177/edit) to provide example code to show what you mean. Alternatively, consider writing this as a comment instead